# Missing a positional argument: 'raw_documents', what does it refer to?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to define vectorizer parameters for use in a model, but python keeps saying that I am missing a parameter. Reviews is a list of restaurant reviews I have web scraped from yelp. The problem is occurring with .fit_transform(), I have the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                                 min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1,3))
%time tfidf_matrix = TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(Reviews) 
print(tfidf_matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

You created `tfidf_vectorizer` object but it is not used. You should use `tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(Reviews)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use .fit_transform, you need to pass a list, dict or tuple to iterate over values.

Example:

```
list = ["a" , "b" , "c"] #Here is your data
TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(list)
```

Is important that you dont have null, or none values on your set of data.

If you have only one value you can also do this and it works

```
list = ["Only Value"]
TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(list)
```